# Errors in playsound

Tags: python

I am trying to use sound in one of my programs, so I decided to use `playsound`. However, I am unable to use it as it is giving me an error. And yes, I did install the `playsound` package.

Here is the code I used to import it:

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound('/path/note.wav')
```

Here is the error it is giving:

```
from playsound import playsound
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'playsound'
```

Also, please note that I am a mac user.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try re-installing playsound - Run `pip uninstall playsound` and `pip install playsound` in your terminal
2. Instead of `from playsound import playsound`, simply import the module using `import playsound`
3. Use a different module - The pygame module is very useful for playing sounds.

```
import pygame
pygame.mixer.init()
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("sound.wav")
sound.play()
```

Comment: Does this work with mp3 files?

Comment: Yes, it should work.